# No OATH login window with codingrally

Tags: eclipse, code-rally

Today I have tried to set up codingrally in my eclipse but i fail when I try to join a race with my car. 
In the server menu, i can log to every servers with any random name I pick and it says i'm successfully logged in. I don't have any oath login window that pop and ask me to log through gmail/twitter or what ever.
Since the login process is not valid, i can't join any race with my car, even though it says i'm connected
Any idea?
I'm running on eclipse neon and I really have the feeling that my set up is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Code Rally servers do not have OAuth enabled for login, so that login procedure was correct.